# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel from plugin to web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, plugins, certificate

I have a problem with my plugin when I try to use a method from service reference. I have a **client** that sends parameters to a **web service**, that then sends those parameters to **my plugin**, then I have to take those parameters and send them to a **web service** using a **web reference method**. To access the web service I need to use a certificate that was sing by the company that owns the last web service. The code that I use is this:

```
BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding
            {
                Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity
                {
                    Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
                    {
                        ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate
                    }
                }
            };

UploaderServiceClient client = new UploaderServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(args.EndPoint));

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocaMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, args.SerialNum);

client.approveTransportDocument(appC, FileDesc);
```

After I use this code I get an exception:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

The last web service works fine and the certificate is valid because if I use the same code on a form it works fine.
EDIT:
I'm adding the exception I get maybe it will help:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'imas-ws.vmi.lt'.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Eur_Iz.Ie.UploaderService.submitTransportDocument(TransportDocument
>   LocalTransportDocument, FileDescription ContextInformation,
>   AdditionalContext AdditionalContext)    at
>   Eur_Iz.Ie.UploaderServiceClient.submitTransportDocument(TransportDocument LocalTransportDocument, FileDescription ContextInformation,
>   AdditionalContext AdditionalContext) in u:\DPb\Plns\Eur_Iz\Service
>   References\Ie\Reference.cs:line 3295    at
>   Eur_Iz.ClientPlugin.DataHandling(IServicePluginArgs args)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer the problem was I had to give permission for the web service to use the certificate. Heres the link that helped me: https://serverfault.com/questions/131046/how-to-grant-iis-7-5-access-to-a-certificate-in-certificate-store/132791#132791

Answer (score 1):

It could be something with client certificate or server certificate. It could be trust issues (CA certificates missing at client or server).

Enabling CAPI2 log in eventlog might give you the answer why it `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.` CAPI2 log is by default disabled. When you enable it try to make the request again. There should be some error events that will contain helpful info about the cause.
[image: CAPI2 event log]