# the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure using imap

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-4.5, imap, servicepointmanager

I wrote a NET 4.5 client application tool using an IMAP require and a SMTP send command.

Now my current issue is I get the following exception at one client:

> the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure

I changed the code to:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

So all certificates should be accepted. The server needs SSL. The same connection information is working with outlook or thunderbird without errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be something with trust issues like missing root CA or intermediate on client/server.

These validation issues can be logged (if you enable it) to CAPI2 event log. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40673031/3245057) might help you.

Comment: Thanks pepo for you answer. With CAPI2 I get the following new exception: The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value
I thought with delegate { return true; }; the error couldn't happen. I can change nothing on the server so I have to fix the problem in the app. Any further ideas to fix it?

Comment: You are calling a different url (or IP?) than is in the certificate either in CN or Subject Alternative Name. If so then change the url.